# Calculating population density in Mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've been trying to color in a layer based on population density and I'm running into some problems. I have two properties in the layer, Area ('ALAND') and population ('B01001_001') that I'd like to use to calculate population density and then use that to fill in. Here's my attempt:

```
map.setPaintProperty('fullcitylayer', 'fill-color', ['interpolate', interpolation: ['linear'], input:['/', ['get', 'B19001_017'], ['/',['get', 'ALAND'],1000000]], stop_input1: 10, stop_output1: '#00adef', stop_input2: 100, stop_output2: '#212529', stop_input3: 1000, stop_output3: '#ea950b', stop_input4: 5000, stop_output4: '#e94e34'] )
```

For some reason I keep getting a syntax error when I attempt to run this. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Copied over from the [github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5685) I answered your question:

You still have to write valid JavaScript in order to make expressions work

Your issue is with lines like `['interpolation', interpolation: ['linear'], ...]`. You can't "label" the array items like this, their purpose is already determined by the position in the array/expression. Expressions always take the form of `[<operator>, <arg1>, <arg2>, <argN>, ...]`. So your expression should look something like this:

```
[
  'interpolate',
  ['linear'],
  ['/', ['get', 'B19001_017'], ['/', ['get', 'ALAND'], 1000000]],
  10,
  '#00adef',
  100,
  '#212529',
  1000,
  '#ea950b',
  5000,
  '#e94e34'
];
```

Comment: Ahhh yeah that make a lot more sense. I think what I was getting caught up on was the fact that I was using "arbitrary expressions" which I thought skirted some typical javascript rules. Hah. Thanks! This was super helpful.